# How do I solve this differential equation $y'' + y^2 = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + y^2 = 0$

I tried in the following way:

$y' =u.$ Therefore $y'' = u'$

$u' + y^2 =0$

$\int du = -y^2 \int dx$

$u = -y^2x + c$

$y' = -y^2x +c$

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: If y is dependent on x your integration doesn't work

Comment: Hint : multiply the original ode by $y'$ and integrate

Comment: This is a special case of the Weierstrass' $\wp$ function. In general $\wp''=6\wp^2-(g_2/2)\wp$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y''=-y^2$$
Multiply bt $2y'$ both sides to get
$$2y'y''=-2y^2y' \implies \frac{d}{dx}(y'^2)=-2y^2 \frac{dy}{dx}.$$
Integrating both sides w.r.t $x$, we get
$$y'^2=-\int 2y^2 dy +A \implies y'^2=\frac{2y^3}{3}+C.$$
$$\implies y'=\pm\sqrt{A+2y^3/3}$$
Integrating ww.r.t. $x$ we have
$$\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{A+2y^3/2}}=\pm \int dx+B$$
$A,B$ are constant of integration to be found by further given conditions.